# Как вывести информацию из файла в div через php?

Tags: php, html

Такой себе проект придумал: создать чат. Допустим, есть текстовое поле и кнопка отправить. Пусть вся информация, которую я записываю сохраняется в файле. Я хочу, чтобы она выводилась в `<div class="layer">  </div>`

Как сделать ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charsеt=utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stl.css">      
</head>
<body>
   <div class="layer">
 
   </div> 
  <div id="send"  >
 <form action="chat.php" method="POST"  >

<input type="submit" name="butto" style="width:150px;height:100px; background-color:#2FA0DC;" class="sn" value="Отправить">
 
 </div>
 <div id="message"   >
 <textarea type="text" style="width:550px;height:100px  " maxlength="250"   name="tex"></textarea>
 
 </form>
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>

<?php
  $tex=$_POST['tex'];
  
  $file=fopen('data chat.txt',"a"); 
  fwrite($file,$tex);

$lines = file('data chat.txt');  // теперь в $lines массив строк файла

  fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: в  <div class="layer">
 
   </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<div class="layer">
   <?php foreach ($lines as $line): ?>
       <div><?php echo $line; ?></div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Только код получения данных перенесите на самый верх.